# JMS transactional message processing pattern with async listener

Tags: design-patterns, transactions, jms

I will shorty describe our system infrastructure and messages flow:

1. There are multiple producers that enqueue messages to QUEUE
2. There is one asynchronous listener (AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE) that collects messages and puts them on a list.

Simplified code:

```
private List<Message> messages;
public void onMessage(Message message) {
      messages.add(messages)
}
```

3. There is one poller that wakes up every interval, grabs all the messages so far dequeued and processes them.

Simplified code (from the listener):

```
   public List<Message> retrieveAndClearMessages() {
      synchronized (messages) {
         List<Message> returnList = new ArrayList<Message>(messages);
         messages.clear();
         return returnList;
      }
   }
```

The problem is that for the duration of the poller are the memory - which means if encounter an outage all the currently processes messages are lost. Are there any enterprise pattern that solves such problems? Maybe some backup queue or other workaround.

Answer (score 0):

the best solution for me is when the poller wakes up, it connects to QUEUE, collect and process messages, if your messages are persisted there is no risk to loose any one of them.

Comment: Messages are being enqueued all the time. This could end up in a situation, where the poller would keep consuming messages on the one side, while producers would keep producing new messages. How can I determine when to stop?

Comment: depends on your business requirements, maybe after a period of time of execution or after a time without receiving messages or  a number of messages processed the poller disconnects